# Powershell Terminates After Few Seconds

Tags: powershell

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I have a weird thing that is happening on my server. I was about to check if a certain script that is running okay on one of my servers on another server with same configuration. However, I realized that once I try to execute it, it will open for a time and start running only to terminate without finishing the whole script. Even doing a `-noexit` can't do anything about it and will immediately terminate the process without showing any error.

I tried to open Powershell console on its own without running any script, and guess what, still closes after a few seconds. Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

All the best!

Comment: This happens only on one system? Check Powershell profiles and Task Scheduler for anything strange.

Comment: Hi @vonPryz. Sorry but Im still new with Powershell. How do I check the profiles? You are correct that this only happens on one system.

Comment: In addition to what @vonPryz suggested, this could also be a result of gpo policies. ask your system-corporate if there are any default settings on this (I'm assuming you are doing this at work)

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6) about profiles. [There are six](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) of those.

Comment: To be explicit: try: [`PowerShell -NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-noprofile)